# Updating a specific module with Conda removes numerous packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have recently started using the Anaconda Python distribution as it offers a lot of Data Analysis libraries out of the box. And using conda to create environments and install packages is also a breeze. But I have faced some serious issues when I want to update Python itself or any other module, I am informed beforehand that a LOT of my existing libraries will be removed.

For example, this is what I get when I use `conda update [package_name]`

```
$ conda update pandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\User\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - matplotlib

The following packages will be REMOVED:
[Almost half of my existing packages]

The following packages will be UPDATED:
[Some packages including my desired library, in this case, pandas]
```

I have searched the web on how to update packages and Python using `conda` and almost everywhere I saw that `conda update [package name]` was suggested. But why doesn't it work for me? I mean it will work but at the expense of tons of important libraries that I need.

So I have tried using the Anaconda Navigator to update the desired libraries (like matplotlib and pandas) hoping that the removal of existing libraries might be a command line issue on my computer. But I had seriously messed up my base (root) environment by updating pandas using Navigator. I didn't get any warnings that a lot of my modules will be removed so I thought I was doing fine. But after the update was done and I wrote some matplotlib code, I wasn't able to run it. I got errors that resembled something that indicated matplotlib was a "non-conda module". So I had to do `conda install --revision n` to go back to a state where I had my modules.

Right now, the only way for me to update any package or Python is to do this:

```
conda install pandas=[package_version_that_is_higher_than_mine]
```

But there's got to be a reason why I am facing this issue. Any help is absolutely appreciated.

EDIT: It turns out that the issue is mainly when I am trying to update using the base environment. When I use my other conda environments, the `conda update [package_name]` or `conda update --all` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anaconda (as distinct from Conda) is designed to be used as a fixed set of package builds that have been vetted for compatibility (see "[*What's in a Name? Clarifying the Anaconda Metapackage*](https://www.anaconda.com/whats-in-a-name-clarifying-the-anaconda-metapackage/)). When you try to introduce new packages or package upgrades into that context, Conda can be rather unpredictable as to how it will solve that. I think it helps to keep in mind that commands like `conda (install|upgrade|remove)` mean requesting a distinct environment *as a whole*, and do not represent low-level commands to change a single package.

Conda does offer some options to get this more low-level behavior. One thing to try is the `--freeze-installed` flag, which would do what you're asking for. Recent versions of Conda do this by default in the first round of solves, and if it doesn't work then it attempts a full solve. There is also the more dangerous and brute force `--no-dep` flag, which won't do a solve at all and just install the package. The documentation for this literally says,

> "*This WILL lead to broken environments and inconsistent behavior. Use at your own risk.*"

Typically, if you want to use newer packages, it is better to create a new env (`conda create -n my_env [pkg1 pkg2 ...]`) because the fact is that you no longer want the Anaconda distribution, but instead a custom one with newer versions.  My personal view is that most non-beginners should be using Miniconda and relegate their **base** env to only having `conda`, while being very liberal about creating envs for projects that have different package requirements.  If you ever need a true Anaconda distribution, there's always the `anaconda` package for that.

Comment: Do you think this might ever get fixed?

Comment: @ArafatKhan the 'fix', as you've discovered, is not to try and update the base environment. If you want a newer version of a package, or one that's not in the base distribution, it's *always* best to create a new environment. Arguably Anaconda Navigator and `conda install` should give you some sort of warning about this.

Comment: @ArafatKhan I updated the answer to be a bit more forthright about all the available options. Just be aware that 1) if you're using the latest Conda (`conda update -c anconda conda`), then Conda already basically does `--freeze-installed` for you, but perhaps try it anyway; and 2) I strongly discourage the use of `--no-dep`.