# conda wants to remove half my packages if I try to update just one (on a fresh Anaconda installation)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3, mamba

## The issue

Today (31-Mar-2023) I downloaded Anaconda, uninstalled an older version and installed today's version on a Windows PC (private PC, no corporate firewall).

As suggested in another question [Conda very slow and downloading only from conda forge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75901180/conda-very-slow-and-downloading-only-from-conda-forge) I removed the .condarc file, which must have been a leftover from a previous installation, as it contained conda-forge as the first repository.

I was testing if conda works properly, and a simple

```
conda update pandas
```

returned the oddest result ever: conda wanted to remove many packages, including numba and matplotlib. I  report the exact text at the bottom.

Why should updating pandas result in the removal of all those packages?

## What I have tried

I installed mamba, and a simple

```
mamba update pandas
```

tells me that `All requested packages already installed` - as one would expect having installed the whole of Anaconda just today

## What I have researched

I hve found a similar issue reported here  https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8842 and [Updating a specific module with Conda removes numerous packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844377/updating-a-specific-module-with-conda-removes-numerous-packages) However, if I understand correctly, in those cases the bug was caused by the fact that, over time, different versions of different packages had been installed, deviating from the anaconda installation. My case is different, because I downloaded Anaconda just today and I haven't changed nor updated any of those packages (the only change was installing mamba). I have been using Anaconda for 9 years and never encountered this.

## The exact output from conda

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:

  alabaster-0.7.12-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  anyio-3.5.0-py310haa95532_0
  appdirs-1.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  argon2-cffi-21.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0-py310h2bbff1b_0
  arrow-1.2.3-py310haa95532_1
  astroid-2.14.2-py310haa95532_0
  astropy-5.1-py310h9128911_0
  asttokens-2.0.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  atomicwrites-1.4.0-py_0
  automat-20.2.0-py_0
  autopep8-1.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  babel-2.11.0-py310haa95532_0
  backcall-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  bcrypt-3.2.0-py310h2bbff1b_1
  binaryornot-0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  black-22.6.0-py310haa95532_0
  bleach-4.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  blosc-1.21.3-h6c2663c_0
  bokeh-2.4.3-py310haa95532_0
  brotli-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7
  brotli-bin-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7
  cfitsio-3.470-h2bbff1b_7
  charls-2.2.0-h6c2663c_0
  cloudpickle-2.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  colorcet-3.0.1-py310haa95532_0
  comm-0.1.2-py310haa95532_0
  constantly-15.1.0-py310haa95532_0
  contourpy-1.0.5-py310h59b6b97_0
  cookiecutter-1.7.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  cssselect-1.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  curl-7.87.0-h2bbff1b_0
  cycler-0.11.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  cytoolz-0.12.0-py310h2bbff1b_0
  daal4py-2023.0.2-py310hf497b98_0
  dal-2023.0.1-h59b6b97_26646
  dask-2022.7.0-py310haa95532_0
  dask-core-2022.7.0-py310haa95532_0
  datashader-0.14.4-py310haa95532_0
  datashape-0.5.4-py310haa95532_1
  debugpy-1.5.1-py310hd77b12b_0
  decorator-5.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  diff-match-patch-20200713-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  dill-0.3.6-py310haa95532_0
  distributed-2022.7.0-py310haa95532_0
  docstring-to-markdown-0.11-py310haa95532_0
  docutils-0.18.1-py310haa95532_3
  entrypoints-0.4-py310haa95532_0
  et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py310haa95532_0
  executing-0.8.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  flake8-6.0.0-py310haa95532_0
  flask-2.2.2-py310haa95532_0
  flit-core-3.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  fonttools-4.25.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  fsspec-2022.11.0-py310haa95532_0
  gensim-4.3.0-py310h4ed8f06_0
  greenlet-2.0.1-py310hd77b12b_0
  h5py-3.7.0-py310hfc34f40_0
  hdf5-1.10.6-h1756f20_1
  heapdict-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  holoviews-1.15.4-py310haa95532_0
  huggingface_hub-0.10.1-py310haa95532_0
  hvplot-0.8.2-py310haa95532_0
  hyperlink-21.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  icc_rt-2022.1.0-h6049295_2
  imagecodecs-2021.8.26-py310h4c966c4_2
  imageio-2.26.0-py310haa95532_0
  imagesize-1.4.1-py310haa95532_0
  imbalanced-learn-0.10.1-py310haa95532_0
  importlib-metadata-4.11.3-py310haa95532_0
  importlib_metadata-4.11.3-hd3eb1b0_0
  incremental-21.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  inflection-0.5.1-py310haa95532_0
  iniconfig-1.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  intake-0.6.7-py310haa95532_0
  intervaltree-3.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  ipykernel-6.19.2-py310h9909e9c_0
  ipython-8.10.0-py310haa95532_0
  ipython_genutils-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  ipywidgets-7.6.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  isort-5.9.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  itemadapter-0.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  itemloaders-1.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  itsdangerous-2.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jedi-0.18.1-py310haa95532_1
  jellyfish-0.9.0-py310h2bbff1b_0
  jinja2-time-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  jmespath-0.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  joblib-1.1.1-py310haa95532_0
  jq-1.6-haa95532_1
  json5-0.9.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jupyter-1.0.0-py310haa95532_8
  jupyter_client-7.3.4-py310haa95532_0
  jupyter_console-6.6.2-py310haa95532_0
  jupyter_server-1.23.4-py310haa95532_0
  jupyterlab-3.5.3-py310haa95532_0
  jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py_0
  jupyterlab_server-2.19.0-py310haa95532_0
  jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  jxrlib-1.1-he774522_2
  keyring-23.4.0-py310haa95532_0
  kiwisolver-1.4.4-py310hd77b12b_0
  lazy-object-proxy-1.6.0-py310h2bbff1b_0
  lcms2-2.12-h83e58a3_0
  libaec-1.0.4-h33f27b4_1
  libbrotlicommon-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7
  libbrotlidec-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7
  libbrotlienc-1.0.9-h2bbff1b_7
  libsodium-1.0.18-h62dcd97_0
  libspatialindex-1.9.3-h6c2663c_0
  libuv-1.44.2-h2bbff1b_0
  libzopfli-1.0.3-ha925a31_0
  llvmlite-0.39.1-py310h23ce68f_0
  locket-1.0.0-py310haa95532_0
  lxml-4.9.1-py310h1985fb9_0
  lz4-3.1.3-py310h2bbff1b_0
  lzo-2.10-he774522_2
  m2w64-libwinpthread-git-5.0.0.4634.697f757-2
  markdown-3.4.1-py310haa95532_0
  matplotlib-3.7.0-py310haa95532_0
  matplotlib-base-3.7.0-py310h4ed8f06_0
  matplotlib-inline-0.1.6-py310haa95532_0
  mccabe-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  mistune-0.8.4-py310h2bbff1b_1000
  mock-4.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  mpmath-1.2.1-py310haa95532_0
  msgpack-python-1.0.3-py310h59b6b97_0
  multipledispatch-0.6.0-py310haa95532_0
  munkres-1.1.4-py_0
  mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py310haa95532_1
  nbclassic-0.5.2-py310haa95532_0
  nbclient-0.5.13-py310haa95532_0
  nbconvert-6.5.4-py310haa95532_0
  nest-asyncio-1.5.6-py310haa95532_0
  networkx-2.8.4-py310haa95532_0
  ninja-1.10.2-haa95532_5
  ninja-base-1.10.2-h6d14046_5
  nltk-3.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  notebook-6.5.2-py310haa95532_0
  notebook-shim-0.2.2-py310haa95532_0
  numba-0.56.4-py310h4ed8f06_0
  numpydoc-1.5.0-py310haa95532_0
  openjpeg-2.4.0-h4fc8c34_0
  openpyxl-3.0.10-py310h2bbff1b_0
  pandocfilters-1.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  panel-0.14.3-py310haa95532_0
  param-1.12.3-py310haa95532_0
  paramiko-2.8.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  parsel-1.6.0-py310haa95532_0
  parso-0.8.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  partd-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  pathspec-0.10.3-py310haa95532_0
  patsy-0.5.3-py310haa95532_0
  pep8-1.7.1-py310haa95532_1
  pexpect-4.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  pickleshare-0.7.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  plotly-5.9.0-py310haa95532_0
  pooch-1.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  poyo-0.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  prometheus_client-0.14.1-py310haa95532_0
  prompt-toolkit-3.0.36-py310haa95532_0
  prompt_toolkit-3.0.36-hd3eb1b0_0
  protego-0.1.16-py_0
  ptyprocess-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  pure_eval-0.2.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  py-1.11.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyasn1-0.4.8-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyasn1-modules-0.2.8-py_0
  pycodestyle-2.10.0-py310haa95532_0
  pyct-0.5.0-py310haa95532_0
  pycurl-7.45.1-py310hcd4344a_0
  pydispatcher-2.0.5-py310haa95532_2
  pydocstyle-6.3.0-py310haa95532_0
  pyerfa-2.0.0-py310h2bbff1b_0
  pyflakes-3.0.1-py310haa95532_0
  pygments-2.11.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyhamcrest-2.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  pylint-2.16.2-py310haa95532_0
  pylint-venv-2.3.0-py310haa95532_0
  pyls-spyder-0.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pynacl-1.5.0-py310h8cc25b3_0
  pyodbc-4.0.34-py310hd77b12b_0
  pyparsing-3.0.9-py310haa95532_0
  pyqtwebengine-5.15.7-py310hd77b12b_0
  pytables-3.7.0-py310h388bc9b_1
  pytest-7.1.2-py310haa95532_0
  python-lsp-black-1.2.1-py310haa95532_0
  python-lsp-jsonrpc-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python-lsp-server-1.7.1-py310haa95532_0
  python-slugify-5.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python-snappy-0.6.1-py310hd77b12b_0
  pytoolconfig-1.2.5-py310haa95532_1
  pytorch-1.12.1-cpu_py310h5e1f01c_1
  pyviz_comms-2.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pywavelets-1.4.1-py310h2bbff1b_0
  pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py310haa95532_1000
  pywinpty-2.0.10-py310h5da7b33_0
  pyzmq-23.2.0-py310hd77b12b_0
  qdarkstyle-3.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  qstylizer-0.2.2-py310haa95532_0
  qtawesome-1.2.2-py310haa95532_0
  qtconsole-5.4.0-py310haa95532_0
  queuelib-1.5.0-py310haa95532_0
  regex-2022.7.9-py310h2bbff1b_0
  requests-file-1.5.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  rope-1.7.0-py310haa95532_0
  rtree-1.0.1-py310h2eaa2aa_0
  scikit-image-0.19.3-py310hd77b12b_1
  scikit-learn-1.2.1-py310hd77b12b_0
  scikit-learn-intelex-2023.0.2-py310haa95532_0
  scipy-1.10.0-py310hb9afe5d_1
  scrapy-2.8.0-py310haa95532_0
  seaborn-0.12.2-py310haa95532_0
  send2trash-1.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  service_identity-18.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  smart_open-5.2.1-py310haa95532_0
  snappy-1.1.9-h6c2663c_0
  sniffio-1.2.0-py310haa95532_1
  snowballstemmer-2.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sortedcontainers-2.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinx-5.0.2-py310haa95532_0
  sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-2.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  spyder-5.4.1-py310haa95532_0
  spyder-kernels-2.4.1-py310haa95532_0
  sqlalchemy-1.4.39-py310h2bbff1b_0
  stack_data-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  statsmodels-0.13.5-py310h9128911_1
  sympy-1.11.1-py310haa95532_0
  tabulate-0.8.10-py310haa95532_0
  tbb-2021.7.0-h59b6b97_0
  tbb4py-2021.7.0-py310h59b6b97_0
  tblib-1.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tenacity-8.0.1-py310haa95532_1
  terminado-0.17.1-py310haa95532_0
  text-unidecode-1.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  textdistance-4.2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  threadpoolctl-2.2.0-pyh0d69192_0
  three-merge-0.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tifffile-2021.7.2-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  tinycss2-1.2.1-py310haa95532_0
  tldextract-3.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tokenizers-0.11.4-py310he5181cf_1
  tomli-2.0.1-py310haa95532_0
  tomlkit-0.11.1-py310haa95532_0
  transformers-4.24.0-py310haa95532_0
  twisted-22.2.0-py310h2bbff1b_1
  twisted-iocpsupport-1.0.2-py310h2bbff1b_0
  typing-extensions-4.4.0-py310haa95532_0
  typing_extensions-4.4.0-py310haa95532_0
  unidecode-1.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  w3lib-1.21.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  watchdog-2.1.6-py310haa95532_0
  wcwidth-0.2.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  webencodings-0.5.1-py310haa95532_1
  websocket-client-0.58.0-py310haa95532_4
  werkzeug-2.2.2-py310haa95532_0
  whatthepatch-1.0.2-py310haa95532_0
  widgetsnbextension-3.5.2-py310haa95532_0
  winpty-0.4.3-4
  wrapt-1.14.1-py310h2bbff1b_0
  xarray-2022.11.0-py310haa95532_0
  xlwings-0.29.1-py310haa95532_0
  yapf-0.31.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  zeromq-4.3.4-hd77b12b_0
  zfp-0.5.5-hd77b12b_6
  zict-2.1.0-py310haa95532_0
  zipp-3.11.0-py310haa95532_0
  zope-1.0-py310haa95532_1
  zope.interface-5.4.0-py310h2bbff1b_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2022.12.~ --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2023.01.10-haa95532_0
  conda              conda-forge::conda-23.1.0-py310h5588d~ --> pkgs/main::conda-23.3.1-py310haa95532_0
  conda-repo-cli                     1.0.27-py310haa95532_0 --> 1.0.41-py310haa95532_0
  jupyter_core                        5.2.0-py310haa95532_0 --> 5.3.0-py310haa95532_0
  libcurl                                 7.87.0-h86230a5_0 --> 7.88.1-h86230a5_0
  packaging                            22.0-py310haa95532_0 --> 23.0-py310haa95532_0
  pcre2                 conda-forge::pcre2-10.37-hdfff0fc_0 --> pkgs/main::pcre2-10.37-h0ff8eda_1
  pkginfo                             1.8.3-py310haa95532_0 --> 1.9.6-py310haa95532_0
  reproc              conda-forge::reproc-14.2.3-h8ffe710_0 --> pkgs/main::reproc-14.2.4-hd77b12b_1
  reproc-cpp         conda-forge::reproc-cpp-14.2.3-h0e605~ --> pkgs/main::reproc-cpp-14.2.4-hd77b12b_1
  requests                           2.28.1-py310haa95532_0 --> 2.28.1-py310haa95532_1
  sqlite                                  3.40.1-h2bbff1b_0 --> 3.41.1-h2bbff1b_0
  tornado                               6.1-py310h2bbff1b_0 --> 6.2-py310h2bbff1b_0
  tqdm                               4.64.1-py310haa95532_0 --> 4.65.0-py310h9909e9c_0
  urllib3                           1.26.14-py310haa95532_0 --> 1.26.15-py310haa95532_0
  zstd                                     1.5.2-h19a0ad4_0 --> 1.5.4-hd43e919_0
```

## EDIT - UPDATE:

I gave up on Anaconda. I installed mambaforge on a PC without a proxy, and miniforge on a PC which accesses the internet via a proxy. mamba is faster than conda but doesn't work behind certain proxy/firewalls.
I now have smaller environments with only the packages I need.

I still have no idea what caused the problem.

Comment: Same issues with Ancaonda 23.3.1 in Windows 11. 

After running "conda update -n base conda" the environment is destroyed. Most of the core packages were removed.

Comment: I now use mamba (much faster) on my private PC but unfortunately I cannot use it behind a corporate firewall, only conda works there

Comment: I am encountering the same issue with Anaconda3-2023.03-1 64-bit on Windows 10. I did a full uninstall of my previous installation with the help of `anaconda-clean`. I don't think I had any leftover files from the previous installation.

Comment: Did you install mamba through `conda install`? Or through `pip install`?

Comment: @aparajito neither - I installed mambaforge (look it up) directly

Comment: Same issue here, did clean uninstall, then installed again. I uninstalled yet again, removing registry entries and nothing, same problem. Try to update any package leads to most of the packages to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues when trying to update certain individual packages. The following helped me to resolve the issues.
Instead of updating individual packages, I did a full update of all packages (insofar possible based on dependencies) as per the instructions here: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/keeping-anaconda-date

```
conda update --all
```

NOTE: please read about this command before using it!

When running this command, the updater wanted to remove half of my packages, some of which I'm actually using. I browsed through the list and made a note of the 10 or so packages that I recognized as ones that I need.

Then I went ahead with the update and indeed the long list of packages was removed in the update.

However, after that I was able to simply re-install the packages that I need, and this did not result in further compatibility issues. So, upon re-installing the packages that I need, I did not meet further issues with other packages being removed by the installer.

All this takes some time of course, and it may not be the desired solution for everyone. However, in my case I did end up with an updated environment containing all the packages that I need, nicely up-to-date.